# How do use PrintWriter object as a function argument and use that function for recursive tree traversal

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, printwriter

I have a binary tree traversal method which is declared in the following way in Java:

```
public void printInPreorder(PrintWriter writer)
```

I need to use recursion on this function to achieve tree traversal for preorder traversal. However, I'm not sure how to pass the `"writer"` object that has been passed as an argument to the function.
(this writer object has been initialized in another class where the filename has been set , also, I cannot change this function's parameters and need to use it in the same format). If it helps, the tree is stored in a 1D array.

Can someone please help me on this?

```
public void printInPreorder(PrintWriter writer) {

   //find root node and print it
   //set visited as false for all other nodes
   //traverse the tree recursively to print the preorder traversal

}
```

Comment: You already have the solution, just pass `writer` to the method on the recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

You already have the solution, just pass `writer` to the method on the recursive call.

The parameter `writer` is just a reference to the object on the heap, so you can pass it down the call stack with no problems.

```
public void printInPreorder(PrintWriter writer) {
    ...    
    printInPreorder(writer);    
    ...    
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but since I'm recursively calling the function, how do I pass the existing values. For instance, the nodes that have been visited, (hence, already printed) shouldn't be re-visited. I'm using a boolean type array to mark the visited nodes and setting all the values to false in the beginning. How do I recursively call the function without having to reset the visited nodes back to false in the function?

Comment: Well, you said you cannot change the method's parameters.  You need to treat this method as the root call, and write a second private helper method that actually does the recursion.  In that private method you can pass the writer ***and*** the node to be examined and printed.  This is pretty basic, but providing you the actual code would be robbing you of the chance to figure it out yourself and impeding your education.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that did cross my mind. But I wanted to find a way to achieve it without having to write additional functions. The question was also merely to validate my understanding of the current function declaration, that there is no other way to do it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It cannot be done.  Each recursive invocation must be given the node it is to work on.  If you cannot change the signature you cannot implement what you want without global (within the class) variables where you use a pushdown stack to support the recursion -- a really strange way of implementing it.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for confirming it I suppose. I'll go ahead with creating private methods for recursion